# Number of fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclic-groups, primitive-roots

If $\zeta_n$ is the $n$-th primitive root of unity then $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq Z_n^*$ due to the following map
$$\tau(\zeta_n)=\zeta^n$$

---

I was wondering if we could use this and the Galois Correspondence to find the **number of fields** between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. How could we determine this?

---

I know that if $n$ is prime then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ contains subfields of degree $d$, where $d$ are the divisors of $p-1$.

For example, $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq Z_3^*$ and since $3-1=2$ has divisors $1$ and $2$, the number of fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ is two... is that right? Do these 'sub'fields actually corresponds to the fields themselves in this case?

---

What can we say if $n$ is not prime?

Comment: Not much besides the fact that its Galois Group is abelian and thus it has  *at least* one subgroup of every divisor of its order, which of course is normal and thus every subextension is normal as well.

Comment: So say we had $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6)$.. can we not determine the number of fields between  $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6)$ and  $\mathbb{Q}$? We only know that there is a degree $1, 2, 3$ and $6$ extension... are subfields of the same degree not isomorphic? Thanks

Comment: Well, in the *particular case* of $\;n=6\;$ it is very easy since the extension is of degree $\;3\;$ and thus cyclic.

Comment: OK, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6) : \mathbb{Q}]=3$. How did you determine this - by finding the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? And is the only group of order $3$ $\mathbb{Z_3}$? Thanks

Comment: In my above comment there's a typo: it should be ",,,of degree $\;2\;$ , and this is because $\;\phi(2n)=\phi(n)\;$ for any odd $\;n\;$ , and the degree of the cyclotomic extension is precisely $\;\phi(n)\;$ . In our case, $\;\phi(6)=2\;$ . You can also directly see it: $$x^6-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ The primitive roots of unit of order $\;6\;$ are from the last quadratic above, as the other quadratic's roots are, of course, the primitive **cubic** roots.

Comment: So $\phi(6)=\phi(3)=x^2+x+1 \implies [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6) : \mathbb{Q}]=2$. Where do the cubic roots come from?  (sorry I find this topic very hard)

Comment: This is one of the most beautiful and amazing, in my opinion, subjects in undergraduate mathematics. Now, you surely meant that the cyclotomoci polynomial $\;\Phi_3(x)=x^2+x+1\;$ , **since** $\;\phi(3)=2\;$ . The *primitive* roots of unit of order three are roots of $\;x^2+x+1\;$ , since $\;x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)\;$ .

Comment: oh ok.. so in general the cylcotomic polynomial $\phi_n(x)$ has primitive roots of order $n$ as roots?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the definition of the cyclotomic polynomial of order $\;n\;$ : $$\Phi_n(x):=\prod_{k=1}^{\phi(n)}\left(x-\zeta_n^k\right)\;,\;\;\;\zeta_n:=e^{2\pi i/n}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40661/discussion-between-amiz9-and-joanpemo).

Answer (score 2):

Recall by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory that the number of fields between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ is the number of subgroups of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n))\cong (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$. If $n$ is a power of a prime, i.e. $n=p^k$ for some $p$ prime and $k\in\mathbb N$, then $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic of order $\varphi(p^k)=p^{k}-p^{k-1}$. By the [fundamental theorem of cyclic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups), for all $d|\varphi(p^k)$ there is exactly one subgroup of order $d$. Hence, the number of intermediate fields between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ is the number of divisors of $p^k-p^{k-1}$. (For example, if $n$ is prime, then this is the number of divisors of $n-1$ as you stated.)

If $n$ is not a power of a prime, this question becomes much more difficult (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46115/subgroups-of-a-finite-abelian-group). By the way, for any finite abelian group $G$, there exists some cyclotomic field $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ and some intermediate field $\mathbb Q\subset F\subset \mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ such that $\text{Gal}(F/\mathbb Q)\cong G$. This provides a trivial partial answer to the [inverse Galois problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem).

Comment: Thank you this clarifies things a lot. So the number of intermediate fields is equal to the number of intermediate subgroups? And when $n$ is not a power of a prime, say we had $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15}) \simeq \mathbb{Z_{15}}^*$.. we would have subgroups of orders $1, 2, 7, 14$... can we say much more?

Comment: Yes, the number of intermediate fields equals the number of subgroups of the Galois group. (Remember that a subgroup $H$ of the Galois group corresponds to its fixed field by the Galois correspondence.) In the case $n=15$, you have $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{15})\cong (\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z)^\times\cong (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times\times (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times\cong \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ (by the Chinese Remainder Theorem). It turns out there are $8$ subgroups of this group, hence 8 intermediate fields (including $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{15})$ and $\mathbb Q$ itself).