# Intermediate Extensions of $\Bbb Q[\zeta_{63}]/\Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\zeta$ be the $63^{th}$ root of unity. The reason why I choose the number $63$ is because $$\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q[\zeta]/\Bbb Q)\simeq (\Bbb Z/63\Bbb Z)^\times\simeq(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\oplus(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\oplus(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)\oplus(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)$$

One could find generators in $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q[\zeta]/\Bbb Q)$ corresponding to the two subgroups of order $3$: $$\left<\sigma_4\right>=\{\operatorname{id},\sigma_4,\sigma_{16}\}$$$$\left<\sigma_{25}\right>=\{\operatorname{id},\sigma_{25},\sigma_{58}\}$$

It turns out from the structure of $(\Bbb Z/63\Bbb Z)^\times$ that the subgroup $\left<\sigma_4,\sigma_{25}\right> = \left<\sigma_2^2,\sigma_{5}^2\right>$ of order $9$ is not cyclic. We could not apply the usual way of writing $$\operatorname{Fix}\left<\sigma_k\right>=\Bbb Q[\zeta+\zeta^k+\zeta^{k^2}+...]$$ but $\operatorname{Fix}\left<\sigma_4,\sigma_{25}\right>$ must also be simple over $\Bbb Q$. How could we compute the primitive element in this case?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808934/number-of-fields-between-mathbbq-and-mathbbq-zeta-n?rq=1). For context, see the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748302/find-intermediate-fields-for-bbb-q-zeta-31-bbb-q).

Comment: The fixed field is a degree four extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. Search this site, and you will find ways of showing that $\sqrt{-7}\in\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ and $\sqrt{-3}\in\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$. Those are both subfields of your field, so the answer is surely $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7},\sqrt{-3})$. I trust you to find a primitive element.

Comment: The limitations of the method of calculating the trace of a primitive root of unity are discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87290/11619).